# Copy-Item does not copy \gpt.ini

Tags: powershell

## I'm trying to copy group policy file from my pc to any other pc but is not copying the gpt.ini. It does copy the rest of the files but not the .ini

```
foreach($line in Get-Content C:\temp\rebranding\computers.txt) {
    if($line -match $regex){
        
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\rebranding\GroupPolicy\gpt.ini" -Destination "\\$line\c$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy" -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A**
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\rebranding\GroupPolicy\Machine" -Destination "\\$line\c$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy" -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\rebranding\GroupPolicy\User" -Destination "\\$line\c$\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy" -Recurse -force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable A
        
                
        "$line Print"
     
     if($A) {
     
     Write-Output "$c Error" | out-file C:\temp\rebranding\1_log.txt -Append
     
     }
}
else
{ 
Write-Output "$c is offline " | Out-File C:\temp\rebranding\1_log.txt -Append
}

   }

Copy-Item : The specified path is invalid.
At line:6 char:3
+         Copy-Item "C:\temp\rebranding\GroupPolicy\gpt.ini" -Destinati ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyIte 
   mCommand
```

Comment: the `Copy-Item` will NOT even see files with 'system' or 'hidden' attributes set ... unless you use the `-Force` parameter.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Look at the code, the `-Force` switch is specified.

Comment: It says the path is invalid, have you verified that? Are you sure the file does exist?

Comment: @marsze - argh! thank you for the correction. i need to go read the docs some more ... this aint the 1st time i have seen your problem, but i can't recall the **_correct_** fix.

Comment: The path does exist